# Нужно получить объект каждого повторяющегося элемента в JSON

Tags: python, json

```
response = requests.get(host, headers=HEADERS)
drop_igrok = response.json()['Value']['SC']['S'][0]['Value']

[{"CS":3,"CV":6,"V":6},{"CS":3,"CV":11,"V":2},{"CS":3,"CV":7,"V":7},{"CS":0,"CV":7,"V":7}]
```

Как мне получить все CS с их значениями?

Comment: не удаляйте код из вопроса: без него непонятен ответ ))

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers
К сожалению код не работает

Comment: где вы получаете такую ошибку, в какой строке?

Comment: drop_igrok = response.json()['Value']['SC']['S'][0]['Value']
cs = [i['CS'] for i in drop_igrok]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
[{"CS":3,"CV":11,"V":2},{"CS":2,"CV":11,"V":2},{"CS":2,"CV":7,"V":7},{"CS":1,"CV":13,"V":4},{"CS":3,"CV":9,"V":9}]

Comment: значит мое предположение про `drop_igrok = [{"CS":3,...` было ошибочным...  откуда взялся список, что у вас в вопросе и что на самом деле находится  в drop_igrok?

Comment: response = requests.get(host, headers=HEADERS)
drop_igrok = response.json()['Value']['SC']['S'][0]['Value']
print(drop_igrok)
cs = [i['CS'] for i in drop_igrok]
print(cs)
Содержание drop_igrok: [{"CS":3,"CV":11,"V":2},{"CS":2,"CV":11,"V":2},{"CS":2,"CV":7,"V":7},{"CS":1,"CV":13,"V":4},{"CS":3,"CV":9,"V":9}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 35, in <module>
    cs = [i['CS'] for i in drop_igrok]
  File "", line 35, in <listcomp>
    cs = [i['CS'] for i in drop_igrok]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: хм... и print(type(drop_igrok)) дает в ответ list, а print(type(drop_igrok[0])) - dict?

Comment: <class 'str'> :D

Comment: добавил в ответ `ast.literal_eval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, и в drop_igrok - список словарей:

```
drop_igrok = [{"CS":3,"CV":6,"V":6},{"CS":3,"CV":11,"V":2},{"CS":3,"CV":7,"V":7},{"CS":0,"CV":7,"V":7}]
```

то список значений ключа 'CS':

```
cs = [i['CS'] for i in drop_igrok]
```

В cs будет:

```
>>> cs
[3, 3, 3, 0]
```

---

UPD если в drop_igrok - строка (не понимаю, как...) - предварительно переведите ее в список

```
import ast

drop_igrok_list = ast.literal_eval(drop_igrok)
cs_value_list = [i['CS'] for i in drop_igrok_list]

print(cs_value_list)
```

Comment: Thanks! Проблема решена!

Comment: @Mark_Markov You are welcome!